# Custom grammar for Android speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying to apply the custom grammar for speech recognition. I have found a lot of documentation about android.speech.recognition package, it seams as the good place to start, but it seams that it doesn't exist in the Android SDK..

Is there a way to apply a custom grammar rules to the android speech recognition at all..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Android's recognizer intent only supports two language models. These are the "Free Form" model and the "web search" model. It does not support custom grammars.

See 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL

Comment: Is this still the case 4.5 years later?
archives like this make it look like there is some sort of interface http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/speech/srec/Recognizer.java

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use one of these libraries to do it:

Pocket Sphinx:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

or
http://jvoicexml.sourceforge.net/