# how to implement speech recognition android with specific words?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i am trying to implement speech recognition in an android project. The plan is to ask the user a question; for example, "would you like to attend reigndance?", and the user can say "yes", "no" or "maybe" for their RSVP to the event. Now since we only need these 3 words for the application, what would be the simplest way to add this functionality?

Any and every bit of help is appreciated.

cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class, and also at the [onResult(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onResults%28android.os.Bundle%29) method. You can retrieve an `ArrayList` of the possible recognition results there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a context-free grammar that will describe your language. In JSGF format it can be something like `<answer> = yes | no | maybe;`. The problem is that system default recognizer does not support grammars (see [Custom grammar for Android speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170154/custom-grammar-for-speech-recognition)), so you will have to use third-party libraries like [pocketsphinx for Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it worked by creating an arraylist in the onresult method, and searching for words in an IF statement block ! Cheers! :D