# Android SpeechRecognizer or RecognizerIntent custom Grammar section

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

There are a number of posts here that talk about the RecognizerIntent and SpeechRecognizer and that it does not support custom Grammar sections. Most of those posts are from a few years ago.  With Google Now, Google appears to be doing it with "ok google", and I'm wondering if there is a way to do it now.

I also noticed that it appears that Nuance is the back end for what Android is using for the ASR. I know that the nuance engine supports custom grammar sections, and that Google appears to be using them, but are those JNI interfaces exposed, maybe just in an undocumented way?

I am basing a lot of these assumptions on this source repository
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/speech/srec/Recognizer.java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom grammar for Android speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170154/custom-grammar-for-android-speech-recognition)

Comment: That is from 2010. I could ask there if anything has been updated, but I felt the chances of that being monitored were slim.

Comment: If you want answers it's probably easier to add a bounty to original question, not to create another one.

Comment: But that question was answered, in 2010.